# Issue with @import in Chrome but not in live preview

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, import

I'm creating a simple HTML/CSS based website for a certain assignment and I've run into a smaller issue.

I had around 500 lines of code in my `main.css` file and it was getting hard to read and scroll through, so I've decided to split it into several `.css` files and link all of them into one with the `@import` function.

Now then, I've still got the `main.css` file in my main folder, and inside it the following:

```css
@import url('/css/first.css')
@import url('/css/second.css')
.
.
.
@import url('/css/last.css')
```

I'm using Brackets as an editor, and while everything works perfectly with Brackets live preview, apparently, when I run the page manually via Chrome (by double clicking the `index.html`), the CSS doesn't appear at all.

Yes, `/css/` is the folder inside the main folder containing all other `.css` files. And yes, the live preview from Brackets also uses Chrome.

Comment: In live previews you must also include the server path, if you haven't. You could probably also use `@import url("mystyle.css");`. Hope my answer helps you out.

Comment: I've tried using @import url('mystyle.css') it's still the same.

Comment: Then you'd probably need to get the correct path to the `css`, what is your map structure? As you now call for a `/css/first.css` inside the folder where the current `css` is located

Comment: Have you cleared your cache in the browser? live preview from brackets has no cache on the requests it's making, while Chrome direct view will cache the file if possible. Clear cache and try again.

Comment: I've also tried cleaning the cache inside Chrome, no effect.
Regarding the map structure, there's a single folder on my desktop, with 2 subfolders (images and css). All .html files are in the main folder, and all .css files except the main.css are inside the css folder.

Answer (score 0):

The `@import` rule could calls in multiple styles files. These files are called by the browser or User Agent when needed e.g. HTML tags call the CSS.

try this below code

```
@import url("../css/first.css");
@import url("../css/second.css");
@import url("../css/last.css");
```

Or you can add your css by using link tag in html between  tag

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/first.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/second.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/last.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code just backtracks 1 map and then searches in that location for a `css` map and the file. Plus this isn't a valid answer, as you do not know the current map structure and this answer hasn't been explained.

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: That works/worked, but I don't want to include 3-4 css files each time I have a new .html file on my page. I'd like to know why is @import supported in live preview of the editor, but not on the regular basis.

Comment: can you share your website link?

Comment: There isn't an actual website since I don't have/own a server, it's just being 'hosted' on my domain.

Comment: Have you tried: `@import "../css/first.css";` In my opinion you only should use `url()` if you are defining more attributes like `portrait` afterwards. If this does not work try clearing you cache or force the reload by adding `?randomstring` to your main css file inclusion.

Comment: It doesn't work at all if the url() is missing. Could you elaborate the ?randomstring adding?